# The type or namespace name 'IAuthorizationState' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, google-oauth

I am using Google-Auth Calendar API with MVC4 and i am facing this error: 
"The type or namespace name 'IAuthorizationState' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
Here are my namespaces:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using HRBC.Areas.Admin.Models;
using HRBC.Controllers;
using HRBC.Models;
using HRBC.Web;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Xml;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;
using System.IO;
//using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth;
//using Google.Apis.Plus.v1;
using Google.Apis.Util;
using Google.Apis;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Calendar;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Authentication;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Configuration;
```

And i am using this code to call a api and refresh token:

```
private static CalendarService CreateService(string token)
    {
        //KeyValuePair<string, string> credentials = Ninject.Web.Common.Get3LOCredentials();
        var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, "CLient ID", "Client Secret");
        //provider.ClientIdentifier = clientID;
        //provider.ClientSecret = clientSecret;
        var auth = new Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, (p) => GetAuthorization(provider, token));
        CalendarService service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            Authenticator = auth,
            ApiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIkey"].ToString(),
            GZipEnabled = false
        });
        return service;
    }

    private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg, String Refreshtoken)
    {
        IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar });
        state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
        state.RefreshToken = Refreshtoken;
        return state;
    }
```

And i donot know what i am missing here. I have include everything for this. Please HELP ME.

Comment: Some times u have to add a reference in the project, try with Add reference

Comment: I have already added the reference of all there namespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the reference again after deleting it. If you're using tfs or any other repository, then there's a possibility of broken references.